# Input/Load data for a Tabbed HTML form from Spring Controller GET method

Tags: html, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc, tabbed-interface

I want to load a single page with multiple tabbed HTML form (with JSP, Bootstrap, JS, AJAX offcourse) from a Spring controller using GET method. Here different tabs will take input or show data from different tables.

Like, tab_1 will input data and will save in TABLE_A, tab_2 will input data and will save in TABLE_B with a reference from TABLE_A.

What should be the optimized way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Getting the tabs from controller is a bad idea. rather you could use some template thymeleaf or sitemesh. then connect the form with spring usual way

Comment: Then, I believe it is possible to load data from DB or POST data to DB is possible from the thymeleaf tabs.... Am i correct?